# Import a local (existing) git repo into Aptana 3

Tags: git, aptana

I had installed Git, edited files with Notepad++ and used GitBash to commit my changes in some local repositories. Some of them are published to GitHub, some were cloned from project sites. But now, Notepad++ is not satisfying any more.

So, I'm trying to get Aptana to work. Of course, I want to use the existing git repositories as projects-to-be. *But how do I do that?* The git import wizard (File->Import->Git Repository as new Project) seems to clone the repo into a new project folder, which I don't want.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [eclipse import existing git project](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7017653/1048572) - but there is no solution either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to create a new project within Aptana Studio, using the existing project folder. Let say you have a project that resides in `project_folder`.

1. If you are not sure about anything, backup your project first.
2. Go to `File -> New -> Choose the type of project you wan`t
3. On the pop
   up windows asking about the detail, point the `Location` to the
   exisiting project, in this case `/some_path/project_folder`
4. Create a new project will generates a `.project` file in your project folder, so you might want to put that into `.gitignore` so that it won't get pushed to the central repo.

Comment: I was quite sure that this would call `git init` on that folder, deleting my history.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, although it warned me that "*the selected location already contains pre-existing files. Creating the project may overwrite the content, and once created, deleting this project later may delete this content.*"

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck with this for a minute, but I found a simple solution without needing additional plugins, etc.

On Windows (and possibly other OSs): If you're importing a repo that's hosted locally or on a mapped drive, try `File -> Import -> Git -> Git Repository as New Project`. Click `Next` and insert the absolute file path for the `URI`. An example would be `file:///O:/projects/sharedproject.git`.

This should clone the repo into your workspace with Git already initialized.

---

I realized after posting this that I posted to the wrong question, but maybe someone will find this useful anyway. Hope this helps.