# Git repository seems empty while opening in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, workspace

I am using GitHub for sharing my code. I cloned the code from the server to my local repository and can see all my projects in the Windows Explorer.

But when i make this my Eclipse Workspace and open it in Eclipse, it seems to be empty. I can't see any projects there.

Why not?

Comment: What are you doing exactly, if you tell whole process then someone could help you.

Comment: Okie.I cloned a project from my github server into a folder in my desktop.I want to work on this project.So now my project is there in the folder and i can see it in windows explorer.Then i opened eclipse and changed my workspace as this folder.But i couldn't see any projects there.The workspace seems empty.This is my problem

Comment: Nevaeh, you just need to import your project. Go to import-> existing code-> select your project-> that's it

Comment: yes.but all the cloned files got overwritten

Comment: try this ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017653/eclipse-import-existing-git-project

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396349/eclipse-egit-clone-project-into-workspace

Comment: and this might help u also...http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#usingegit_createproject..:)

Comment: This is not the right way to do it.  You _must_ use a form of import to have Eclipse create the right infrastructure for your sources.

Comment: @Nevaeh http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52644/discussion-about-git-import join this

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen how to do that ??

Comment: @Nevaeh create a new workspace elsewhere, and import your current sources.

Comment: @Nevaeh..have you try... file -> import -> git -> projects from git -> local -> add -> Browse ( add path of your project ) -> finish -> finish

Comment: there is no "git" in my import menu

Comment: no probs.its fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import that projects into eclipse

Click on File->Import...

Select "Existing Android Code Into Workspace" from Android

Click Next

Select your projects from your workspace

Thats it... You are done...!

Answer (score 0):

its very simple you need to import it even you set it as your workspace . open eclipse click file > import>General>existing project into workspace> and chose your workspace folder or any specific project .. 
Thank you

Comment: man first time you have to do it . without import eclipse doesn't recognize them . ok he knows only workspace folder but he doesn't know what the content you have to put in your workspace folder may be it would be a image, vedio , audio etc so you need to say to eclipse  that its your project ...

Comment: but when i imported,all the files i pulled was overwritten and now i have lot of uncommited changes

Comment: may be first time it will happen . some months ago i have done this , but now exactly i cant say whats going on ... but remember without any import you will never found you project in your eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I redid everything again from scratch. Seems like it was some problem with the cloning and the repository. It is working fine now.